# SQL subquery logic confusion

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, join

I'm writing an SQL query but I'm stuck at a point and can't figure out how to solve this issue. First have a look at the query below:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM hwc_attend 
WHERE at_id IN 
    (SELECT evdet_id
     FROM eve_detail
     WHERE evdet_id IN (SELECT at_id FROM hwc_attend WHERE attendstate=1 )
       AND location <> ''
       AND evdet_id > 999
       AND location NOT IN (SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews )
    )
GROUP BY user_id
```

This query is working fine but giving lesser results than required because the part `SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews` should be like `SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews where cID={place current value of "location" field from table eve_detail here`.

For a better understanding, here's the errornous query:

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) as count 
FROM hwc_attend 
WHERE at_id IN 
    (SELECT evdet_id **, location**
     FROM eve_detail
     WHERE evdet_id IN (SELECT at_id FROM hwc_attend WHERE attendstate=1)
       AND location <> ''
       AND evdet_id > 999
       AND location NOT IN (SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews where cID=**location**)
    )
GROUP BY user_id
```

It's hard to explain.. In short, I have to remove "location" values from the result fetched from table "eve_detail" that also exist in table "pReviews" in column cID.

Additionally, it would be nice if someone can covert it into joins. I would need both queries for learning.

Comment: just post data sample to select from and expected result, that would be very helpful. and/or sqlfiddle would be great to start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Translating it to a join would use something like this. Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN and checking for NULL instead of NOT IN. I am assuming that hwc_attend has a unique column called id which is used in the count to get distinct rows.

```
SELECT ha1.user_id, COUNT(DISTINCT ha1.id) as count 
FROM hwc_attend ha1
INNER JOIN eve_detail ed ON ha1.at_id = ed.evdet_id
INNER JOIN hwc_attend ha2 ON ed.evdet_id = ha2.at_id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN pReviews pr ON ed.location = pr.ASIN AND cID = **location**
WHERE ha2.attendstate = 1
AND ed.location <> ''
AND ed.evdet_id > 999
AND pr.ASIN IS NULL
GROUP BY ha1.user_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
AND location NOT IN (SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews )
```

To

```
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ASIN FROM pReviews WHERE eve_detail.location = ASIN.cID )
```

Comment: Not the exact solution but this helped to solve the issue. Thanks.